# Robot class, move the mouse in a circular motion

Tags: java, awt, mouse, awtrobot

What I want to do is make my mouse move in a circular fashion around a point (500px away from said point). I want the mouse to do this anticlockwise.

So what I am trying to say is this.. I want the mouse to move around a point 500px away, using the Robot class method mouseMove. I jsut can't figure out how I would do so in the math side of things.

Comment: I am pretty sure you mean the mouse pointer.  The mouse itself is outside the java virutal machine.

Answer (score 1):

use the [circle equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Equations) to get the dependence between the x value and the y value.

now go over every x between -500 to 500 (jumps of 1), calculate the y value, and move the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

I think little bit [trigonometry](http://relativity.net.au/gaming/java/Trigonometry.html) can do the magic. Then you can move continuously by:

```
Robot r = new Robot();
r.mouseMove(calculatedX,calculatedY);
```